# Android Service stops after 1 minute when called onPause

Tags: android, background-service

I am trying to use a countdown timer which will run when the activity onPause is triggered. However, the service stops after 1 minute. But if I start the service with the activity working it works.

```
public class TimerService extends Service {
    private static CountDownTimer countDownTimer;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        startTimer(2*60 * 1000);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void startTimer(int noOfMinutes) {
        countDownTimer=new CountDownTimer(noOfMinutes, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                long millis=millisUntilFinished;
                String hms=String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
                Log.d("Long Seconds", hms);

            }

            public void onFinish() {
                //timerOn=false;
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Splash_Loader.class);
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        }.start();

    }
}
```

Starting it onPause from an activity

```
 @Override
protected void onPause() {

    super.onPause();
    startService(new Intent(this,TimerService.class));
}
```

Manifest file decleration

```
 <service android:name = ".TimerService"/>
```

Comment: That's the correct behavior of service. You need to start foreground service before 1mn else the service is stopped. ;)

Comment: Is there a way to push it to 4 minutes